# Passing configure option to rpmbuild?

Tags: make, configure, rpmbuild, slurm

To build a piece of software I normally do

```
rpmbuild -ta slurm*.tar.bz2
```

However I now need to configure the software with the option

```
--with-pmix=/home/user/git/pmix/install/2.1
```

Is this possible using `rpmbuild` or do I need to go through the standard `configure/make/make install` proceedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to create SPEC file and make `rpmbuild` to use it. In this file you can incorporate different parameters in build process. You can check [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/Packagers_Guide/sect-Packagers_Guide-Creating_a_Basic_Spec_File.html) for example usage of SPEC file

> 1. In a shell prompt, go into the buildroot and create a new spec file
>      for your package.
> 2. Open the spec file in a text editor. The spec file should be similar
>      to the following example:

```
%build
%configure
make %{?_smp_mflags}
```

> ....
>
> 3. Edit the BuildRequires tag with requirements that are needed to
>      build the package. BuildRequires can contain either a list of
>      required packages or files. For example, the eject package requires
>      the gettext and libtool packages. ....

Comment: Coming back a bit late to this, but how does the SPEC file that I create interact with the SPEC file which is already included in the source RPM?  Do I copy the original file, modify it and pass it as an argument to rpmbuild, or can I somehow just overwrite theconfigure step?

Comment: You can create totally new SPEC file and point it to the `rpmbuild` command. Or you can edit the original SPEC file.

Comment: This is something I will probably have to do on a regular basis, so I do  want to just modify the SPEC file included in the SRPM.  Is there any good way to extract and then reinsert the SPEC file?

Comment: You can install `srpm` file and then you will have SPEC file in the filesystem :)

Comment: I don't know what I might have expected installing an SRPM would do, but simply extracting the SPEC file wasn't it :-) Does anything else happen as well?

Comment: @loris, installing SRPM give you much more options to manipulate not only SPEC but also tar.gz archive. And you have in ``/usr/src` the source :)

Answer (score 2):

I found out what I really want to do, namely

```
rpmbuild --define "_with_pmix --with-pmix=/path/to/pmxi" -ta slurm-19.05.5.tar.bz2
```